# What can I do to maximize illusion/enchantment spells as a sorcerer?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, character-creation, sorcerer

I've read up online but it doesn't seem there are that many people talking about the Sorcerer's *maestro* bloodline. The adventure path I'm doing will be a play-by-post(PbP) roleplay heavy campaign with politics and espionage.  I thought an illusionist/enchanter would be fun. The *maestro* bloodline was suggested as being relevant thematically to the adventure path, and I like the idea of having a music centered character that is not a Bard.

1. How can you maximize spells per day for the *maestro* bloodline without relying too heavily on rare items?
2. How can you maximize illusion and enchantment spell DC with the *maestro* bloodline?  I already will be taking a trait that gives a +1 to illusion pattern DCs.

Comment: Idea generation questions are generally too primarily opinion-based to be answerable here, as there's no way to choose a "best" answer. If you were to ask for a build that maximized damage per round, for instance, there's clearly a way for an answer to be better than the others - but there's no way to say "this build is the best for what you want to do" given such generic parameters.

Comment: I think this also could be broken down into 2-3 questions. One for optimizing build choices (around a specific goal, probably Illusion or Enchantment spell DC or spells per day... or making it so people don't realize you're spellcasting), and 1-2 more about "How does this class feature work?". It's absolutely fine to have multiple, related, questions.

Comment: To be clear, it is totally acceptable to ask multiple, separate questions on a lone topic. I think each of these is a perfectly valid question, but I recommend  here eliminating all but #4 as I think if an answer explains that sufficiently, that answer may, in turn, answer other questions before they need to be asked separately.

Comment: I have them separate because according to d20pfsrd bloodline arcana is a section of the bloodline, not the whole thing. I will paste that section here:     Bloodline Arcana: Whenever you cast a spell with a verbal component and no somatic or material component, you treat your caster level as if it were one higher.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect any changes to it that you've thought of. Comments alone, sadly, aren't enough—the question itself must change. Also, the site has a robust edit feature that saves your previous drafts, so don't worry about "losing" your previous stuff.

Comment: I thought it was clear before, but I've now put that clarification in question #4.

Comment: This should be further separated into different Stack questions (1/2), (3/4/5), and (6). ie "What can I do to maximize Illusion and Enchantment spells as a Sorcerer?", "How do these Maestro Bloodline abilities work?", and "How does a metamagic feat work at low levels?"

Comment: I've changed the question and waiting. Is there something I'm missing that I need to do for my question to come off hold?

Answer (score 1):

You can maximise your low level charm and sound spells with [Runestones of power](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/runestone-of-power/) or even a level one [ring of wizardry](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-wizardry/), and taking [spell focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus/) and the [greater version](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/greater-spell-focus/) ups your DCs.

Note: okay some of those are expensive but they really pay of.

Edit: I found out on [RPGBot](http://rpgbot.net/pathfinder/characters/classes/sorcerer/bloodlines.php) that, unfortunately, maestros ability set is actually under powered. I'm not sure how this would affect your campaign, but this is what i found.

### Class skill:

perform (good if your split classing to bard but situational)

### Bonus spells:

- ventriloquism (OK)
- hideous laughter (good)
- suggestion (good)
- shout (bad)
- dominate person (great)
- mass suggestion (good)
- power word blind (great)
- greater shout (trash)
- wail of the banshee (great)

### Bonus feats:

- Deceitful (trash)
- Greater Spell Focus (enchantment) (Awesome)
- Lingering Performance (trash)
- Persuasive (trash)
- Skill Focus (Perform) (trash)
- Spell Focus (enchantment) (Awesome)
- Spell song (bad)
- Still Spell (good)Bloodline arcana

### Abilities

- Bloodline Arcana: (okay)
- Beguiling Voice (good)
- Fascinate (only OK because you already have spells for this)
- Perfect Voice (bad (cast tongues) )
- Inspire (just cast heroism)
- Grand Maestro (OK but good for free)

**I know its not maximising but for me, maximising would be playing an enchanter wizard with enchanting school, though (Of course) Maestro is way cooler.**

Comment: The character is clearly planned to be a Sorceror, which cannot make use of pearls of power. Runestones of Power are the (more expensive) alternative for spontaneous casters. https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/runestone-of-power/

Comment: Sorry about that